# c# : selecting a variable from several, randomly

Tags: c#-4.0, random, int

I have several independant  int variables in my program. Is there a way I can feed randomly the value of one of them into a new int variable or an int array ? Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:

here's a pseudocode to demonstrate:

```
int A1 = 1;
int A2 = 3;
int RESULT = 0;

Random rand = new Random();

 Result = rand.Next(0, A1 || A2)]; //Result holds the value/variable name of  A1 or A2
```

Comment: Can you add some pseudo-code of what you want to achieve?  I don't think the question is clear, or the purpose of it.  Please expand.

Comment: @agarcian, I added as you requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all the ints you want to choose from in a new array and then select a random value from it. For example:

```
int value1 = 3;
int anotherValue = 5;
int value2 = 1;

int[] selectableInts = new int[3] { value1, anotherValue, value2 };

Random rand = new Random();

int randomValue = selectableInts[rand.Next(0, selectableInts.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
// create an array of your variables
int[] A = new int[] {1,3};

// Instantiate Random object.
Random rand = new Random();

// Get a value between 0 and the lenght of your array.  
// This is equivalent to select one of the elements of the array.
int index = rand.Next(0,A.Length);

// Get the value from the array that was selected at random.
int Result = A[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble myself and found this thread, but its code is for Ints only, so I was stuck for some time to make it work for other than ints.
I think @David gave me some idea how to make it work. 
This is my version for using types other than ints.

```
Vector2 down = new Vector2(0, 1);
Vector2 left = new Vector2(-1, 0);
Vector2 right = new Vector2(1, 0);

List<Vector2> possibleDirections = new List<Vector2>()
{ 
    down,
    left,
    right
};

Random random = new Random();

Vector2 selectedRandomDirection = possibleDirections[random.Next(0, possibleDirections.Count)];       

// this is the result
Vector2 direction = selectedRandomDirection;
```